# Filtering SQL Query using predefined filters

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, filtering

I've pasted my code below. What I'm trying to do is filter a set of data using the day. The 'day' field is stored as the abbreviated day name, so "thu" for Thursday etc. This works perfectly fine, except once you've changed the date filter to something else, the option for the current day doesn't work.

For example, today is Sunday. When the page loads, it filters out all listings that are not for Sunday, as it should. On a small group of `LinkButton` controls, if you click any other day of the week, it will change and show the option for the selected day, again, as it should do. However, when you try and set the filter to Sunday again, or click the "today" button, it won't change.

Based on my code, can anyone see what is wrong? If it is of any help, my data is on a remote SQL server.

VB Code:

```
Dim DateVal As Date = DateTime.UtcNow()
Dim DateName As String = DateVal.ToString("ddd")

Protected Sub btnMon_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMon.Click
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("FiltDay").DefaultValue = "Mon"
End Sub

Protected Sub btnTue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTue.Click
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("FiltDay").DefaultValue = "Tue"
End Sub

Protected Sub btnWed_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWed.Click
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("FiltDay").DefaultValue = "Wed"
End Sub

Protected Sub btnThu_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnThu.Click
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("FiltDay").DefaultValue = "Thu"
End Sub

Protected Sub btnFri_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFri.Click
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("FiltDay").DefaultValue = "Fri"
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSat_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSat.Click
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("FiltDay").DefaultValue = "Sat"
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSun_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSun.Click
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("FiltDay").DefaultValue = "Sun"
End Sub

Protected Sub btnAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnToday.Click
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("FiltDay").DefaultValue = DateName
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("FiltDay").DefaultValue = DateName
End Sub
```

TSQL (If it helps)

```
SELECT        Schedule.SlotID, RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Schedule.StartHr), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Schedule.StartMin), 2) AS StartTime, 
                     Schedule.ProgrammeID, Schedule.Day, RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Schedule.EndHr), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Schedule.EndMin), 2) 
                     AS EndTime, Programmes.ProgrammeName, Programmes.Description, Programmes.PresenterID, Presenters.PresenterName, Presenters.PhotoURL
FROM            Presenters CROSS JOIN
                     Programmes CROSS JOIN
                     Schedule
WHERE        (Schedule.Day = @FiltDay)
```

Comment: A CROSS JOIN ? Do you really need a Cartesian product of all the possible combinations?

Comment: In button click handlers, maybe you should call `DataBind` for the control that displays your data?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is not 100% related to your issue but you should not handle the datasource initialization on the event of a different control.

your need is to fill the sql parameter so you should handle the [Selecting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event of the datasource.

on click of your buttons set the proper value for your variable `DateName` and on selecting of the datasource fill the sql parameter using your variable.

acting this way you can easily spot the actual value fed into the call and identify the issue.